# Import python script into powerBI and publish dashboard

Tags: python, powerbi

I am using power bi and sourcing the python script file1.py. However, since the file is stored locally in my C: drive, I cannot use the published dashboard. How can I store file1.py on my workspace online and call it?

Code in power bi is:

```
exec(open("C:\\file1.py").read())
```

Screenshot of the error[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support)

"The Power BI service supports packages published in PyPI. The service does not support private or custom Python packages. Users are encouraged to make their private packages available on PyPI prior to requesting the package be available in the Power BI service."

If you can't paste the contents of your file1.py directly into the Python Script GUI, you'll have a hard time. But anyhow: What are you aiming for?

Comment: I am using python for a custom visualisation. I presently have the Python code pasted into the Python Script GUI as you suggested. But this approach is not scalable as I cannot be pasting the code 70-80 times every time there is an edit. I wanted to have a single source of the code that I could import instead.